# How to notify Google of a new page appeared of the site

Tags: google, sitemap, search-engine-indexing, yahoo

I have a blog website coded by me (not Wordpress or any). I'd like to automatically notify Google (and other search engines like Bing, Yahoo...) each time I add a new post.

From my prospective I see the following ways to do it:

1. Add my site to **Google Analytics** (actually I doubt that this will help to index my site at all),
2. Add my site to **Google Webmasters Tools** (same doubts untill I will upload Sitemap)
3. Submit new sitemap with `http://www.google.com/ping?sitemap=URL/of/file` for **Google**, `http://www.bing.com/ping?sitemap=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com/sitemap.xml` for **Bing** (unfortunately I wasn't able to find http request for **Yahoo**).

So I will do 1-st and 2-nd anyway as it will help to understand how the site is performing. However I think that these steps are not helping site for indexing and ranking.

So my questions are:

1. Is that correct that adding a site to *Google Webmasters Tools* and *Google Analytics* is **not helping** for indexing and ranking?
2. Can I do anything else **externaly** (I'm not discussing the internal structure of the site - it's a big topic for another question) after submiting sitemap with *pings* above to improve indexing and ranking?
3. Is there a ping for **Yahoo** available?

Comment: Your first mistake is assuming that Google respects notification from pings, sitemaps and so forth. Each site is allocated Google resources, so the Googlebot will return to the site when it's your turn... how often it returns or how long it spends on your site is determined how important Google and Bing consider your site to be, so if your publishing content that has little to no interaction from users then you can expect longer time between indexing of content. Sitemaps, and Pings do not speed up this process.

Comment: External links published on Reddit, Facebook, Twitter and so forth is one of the fastest ways of getting content added. If someone VERY popular retweets your tweet then you can expect a mere instant indexation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) For ranking, it will definitely not help but in regarding indexing it will definitely help for sure.

2)Well if you do well with your websites, do not need to have ping and anything for it.

3)No not available